# How to retrieve data from response body when using trigger URL

Tags: runscope

I am using trigger URL to run a test case created on [Runscope](https://www.runscope.com). In response I am getting only details as shown in Runscope documentation. For eg.

Response Sample data:

```
{
"data": [], 
"error": null, 
"meta": {"status": "success"}
}
```

But I need the data in response body retrieved from server for request made.For eg.

```
{
"Status": "OK",
"Body": [{"userId": 12345,"sessionId": "abcd:1234"}]
}
```

I am using `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` for the same.

Comment: Right now we don't support getting Radar request/response data out via the API. This is on our list for the future though. The most likely route would be adding a request ID to request items in https://www.runscope.com/docs/api/resources/radar#test-run-detail and a URL to retrieve the details from https://www.runscope.com/docs/api/resources/messages#message-detail

Comment: I extracted the response data from test run after saving them as a variable. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something like this :

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/dyson#installation

It is used to mock results via api .