# Retrieve data from response body using Runscope's Trigger URL

Tags: runscope

My question is very similar to "[How to retrieve data from response body when using trigger URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525329/how-to-retrieve-data-from-response-body-when-using-trigger-url)" - I'm also attempting to run a test case created on Runscope using Trigger URL to retrieve data from response body but I am only getting details as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OY8jZ.png).

I've looked through the documentation (https://www.runscope.com/docs/api-testing/integrations#trigger-url-response) but found no answer. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response that you get when you use a Trigger URL is not the result of the test, but an indication of whether you successfully started the test. Included in the response, however, is the `test_run_url` which is a link to the test result (including the requests and bodies for the test). Also included in the response are the `bucket_key`, `test_id`, and `test_run_id` which can be used with the [Runscope API](https://www.runscope.com/docs/api) to retrieve the results of the test via API. See https://www.runscope.com/docs/api/results#test-run-detail for documentation on the endpoint.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now :) 
P.S. I wish Runscope would display test results directly in the response after I open the trigger URL so there would be no need to open the test results separately but that works too.

Comment: We do this because the test takes a little while to run and HTTP clients will time out or act unexpectedly while waiting for the test result. Polling separately ensures there's actually a result ready to be retrieved.